# End Chat System Dialog

Tags: einstein, chat, einstein-chatbot, standard, chatbot

I have a quick question: does the attached image exist in the Einstein chatbot? I saw a few examples of this in old YouTube videos, but they were using older releases of the Einstein chatbot. I'm wondering if this feature is still available in the current version. If so, how can I activate or enable it? Thank you for any response.

Currently I am using Standard Einstein chatbot.

[image]